# Nested React routes only partially working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am organising my React project according to feature - each feature takes care of its own routes. However, the routes defined in the 'sub-apps' only work for the root, other routes return 404. For example ...

```
admin/main.tsx - contains all code for the 'admin' part of the app
main.tsx
```

***main.tsx***

```
// ... imports etc.

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<div>Home</div>} />
          <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminApp />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<div>404</div>} />
        </Routes>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

***admin/main.tsx***

```
// ... imports etc.

export const AdminApp = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<div>Admin Home</div>} />
    <Route path="/:id" element={<div>Admin for ID</div>} />
    <Route path="/foo" element={<div>Admin Foo</div>} />
  </Routes>
);
```

... with this setup visiting `/` and `/admin` gives the expected output, but visiting `/admin/123` and `/admin/foo` returns 404.

`/admin` works so the nested router is definitely being at least partially executed but I can't figure out why the other routes don't seem to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `path="/admin/*"`? Look at e.g. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#how-do-i-nest-routes-deep-in-the-tree, https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links.